# Distinguishing between user tap and programmatic focus on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a unique problem in which I need to distinguish how a UITextField gained focus. There are some differences in the way the UI is handled based on these circumstances. I have a series of text inputs that are generated programmatically.

My first stab at this issue was to place a UITapGestureRecognizer on the UITextField and adding the gesture recognizer in cellForRowAtIndexPath but I have not been able to make the associated method fire.

Most suggestions point to using the UITextField delegate methods, however, these methods all fire regardless of whether the UITextField gained focus through user interaction or programmatically.

Can anyone offer a suggestion, while using the UITextField delegate methods to distinguish between user interaction and a focus gained programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your UITextFields inside a UIView and then add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIView. Then you can use something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:textField];

    //Checks if the tap was inside the text field
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(textField.bounds, location)){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can just add a clear UIButton over the UITextField that, when tapped, programmatically sets the UITextField as the first responder. Using this, you can do all of your logic for user initiated first response in the method called on the button tap.

You can do it in either a subclass of UITextField or just the View Controller / View that the UITextField is in.